# dynamically specify string interpolation for variable in place of column or property value entity framework c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here dynamic_Column variable is not showing a value same as static_Column

Please help me solve the below problem if you can help?

```
var customerList = _context.customers.ToList();
    
for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    var colName = customerList[0].name;//value =id
    
    var static_Column = customerList[i].id;
    var dynamic_Column = $"{customerList[i]}.{colName}";
    
    Console.WriteLine(static_Column);
    Console.WriteLine(dynamic_Column);
}
```

Comment: https://dynamic-linq.net/ ?

Comment: Please clarify, what you expect and what you get. Why would you expect same values in these two variables? colName is not the name of the column - it is the value of `customerList[0].name`

Comment: As you told it is right, customerList[i].id -> Here replace id with variable name. i shown just an example to understand you better!

Comment: The point of entity framework is to be strongly-typed and column aware.  What do you expect to happen if one *dynamic* column is a *bigint* and another is a *nvarchar(200)*?  You can dynamically choose a column, but you're going to run into this `Type` problem.

Comment: You told absolutely right, in my current scenario everything is string and it is fixed. I need a solve this syntax if possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [dynamic-linq.net], It helped me to fix my problem.